# Android crash on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-savedstate

I have a `android.widget.Spinner` inside an `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`. The spinner's items are dynamic and computed at runtime.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val act = activity
    val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false)
    val arrLimits = arrayOf("blah" as String?)

    if (act != null) {
        val spinner = rootView.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.my_spinner)
        spinner?.adapter = ResUtils.createArrayAdapter(arrLimits, act)

        spinner?.onItemSelectedListener = object: OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {
                Log.d(LOG_CHANNEL, "item selected")
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
        }
    }

    return rootView
}
```

This works initially, but as soon as orientation changes, the app crashes.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 7309
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: 
    method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter,
    parameter view at com.example.myapp.fragment.MyFragment$onCreateView$1.onItemSelected
```

Even though the exception looks as if it crashed inside onItemSelected, the `Log.d` is never called. If I comment out the `onItemSelectedListener`, however, the app does not crash on orientation change.

After hours of debugging I begin to suspect that Android tries to restore the state of my fragment's spinner with a value that no longer, or not yet, exists. To verify that, I tried adding the following lines to the fragment:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.clear()
}

override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
    savedInstanceState?.clear()
}
```

and the following to the activity:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
    outState.clear()
}
```

but the app still crashes.

Comment: I overrided `onConfigurationChanged` in both the activity and the fragment as suggested by that answer, but it didn't help.